# Can I create big texture from other small textures in webgl?

Tags: webgl

I have loaded textures in memory and I want to draw them one draw call. I can put all texture coords to buffer but how I create one texture from small texture parts ? is that possible ?

or I must download images and combine them then I create textrute from combined big picture ?

Answer (score 1):

In general combining images into a [texture atlas](https://www.google.com/search?q=texture+atlas) is something you'd do off line either manually like in an image editing program or using custom or [specialized tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=texture+atlas+maker). That's the most common and recommended way.

If you have to do it at runtime for some reason then the easiest way to combine images into a single texture is to first load all your images, then use the canvas 2D api to [draw them into a 2D canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage), then use that canvas as a source for `texImage2D` in WebGL. The only issue with using a 2D canvas is if you need data other than images because 2D canvas only supports pre-multiplied alpha.

Otherwise doing it in WebGL is just a matter of rendering your smaller textures into a larger texture. Rendering to a texture requires creating the texture, attaching to a framebuffer, and then rendering like you would anything else. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56117795/128511) for rendering to a texture and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37222104/128511) for rendering any part of an image to any place in the canvas or another texture.

Comment: those examples above are good. I use texture atas or draw images to 2d canvas and get bigger texture before. But this are expensive processes. I already have 2dtextures in memory I just put them one big texture. May be there is a way whihc is I dont know. But I think its not possible. Thanks for answer.